# Exponentiation in terms of Summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

For positive integers, $a \times b=\sum\limits^{b}{a}$, correct?

So therefore exponentiation where n is also a positive integer should be something like $a^n=\sum\limits^n{\sum\limits^a{a}}$

This is for a proof by induction, and I just want to see if I can simplify the proof enormously by doing this.

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Just a general remark: it would be good practice to use proper notation for summations, i.e. $b \times a = \sum_{i=1}^b a$ or something like that.

Comment: I'm not supposed to use implicit terms then? Makes sense

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle\sum^a a = a^2$

$\displaystyle\sum^n a^2 = na^2$

You need $\displaystyle \sum^a \sum^a \sum^a \sum^a ... \sum^a$ n times to get $a^n$.

$$\displaystyle \sum^a 1= a^1$$

$$\displaystyle \sum^a\sum^a 1= a^2$$
$$\displaystyle \sum^a\sum^a\sum^a 1= a^3 \\ \vdots$$

Consider the case $a = 2$ if you would like a concrete example. Consider the case $a = 1$ if you want a counter example to your formula.

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty much what I was looking for, and I did know about a=1.