# Can Pi prod be expressed using Sigma Notation?

Tags: summation, arithmetic, products

Can $\prod(x)$ be expressed in terms of $\sum (x)$?

Comment: The usual way to turn products into sums is to use logarithms.  That's largely what they are for!

Comment: @Unwisdom: Sums into products!

Comment: Sorry.  But to go the other way, well, take a guess!

Comment: I think the asker is looking for something along these lines: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/708331/8530

Comment: @MatsGranvik: Does this answer help in whatever you were trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\prod_k x_k = \exp\left( \sum_k \ln x_k \right),$$
and as Unwisdom wrote in the comments, if you want to go the other way,
$$\sum_k x_k = \ln \left( \prod_k \exp(x_k) \right).$$

Comment: Could you please explain your answer. A formal proof, perhaps? Or atleast links

Comment: @Nick For finite sums/products, it is just a consequence of these equations:
$$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b) \quad \exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b).$$
For infinite sums and products, you have to take limits and use the fact that both exponentials and logarithms are continuous, but the principle is the same.

Comment: What if $x_k \lt 0$ ?

Comment: if $x_k<0$ then you get a complex number from $\ln x_k$ whose imaginary part is an integer multiple of $\pi$.  When you add all the real and complex numbers in the sum, the imaginary part will still be an integer multiple of $\pi$, so when used as an exponent for $e$, it turns back into a real number, either positive or negative depending if the multiple of $\pi$ is even or odd.